# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for "edge_detection" building flutter iOS app

Tags: flutter

After trying to build a flutter app for iOS I got the following error:

```
$ flutter build ios --no-codesign

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.example.mmpgui for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                              0,8s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

...

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "edge_detection":
    In Podfile:
       edge_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/edge_detection/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `edge_detection (from `.symlinks/plugins/edge_detection/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher
minimum deployment target.

...

Error output from CocoaPods:

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a
    platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

First, I tried to follow the advice in the link and update the Pod file (ios/Pods/Pod)
by setting the platform version to 10.0

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Now it compiled but I got lots of compilation errors:

```
$ flutter build ios --no-codesign

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.example.mmpgui for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                             38.3s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                           665.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

    ** BUILD FAILED **

...

    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC
    /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gjlpspwywczpboarjfvvefatdons/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iph
    oneos/camera.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CameraPlugin.o
    /Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.7+3/ios/Classes/CameraPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
    com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    /Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/edge_detection-1.0.4/ios/Classes/HomeViewController.swift:29:49:
    error: value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'
            var imagePath = saveImage(image:results.scannedImage)
                                                    ^
    /Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/edge_detection-1.0.4/ios/Classes/HomeViewController.swift:29:49:
    note: coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
            var imagePath = saveImage(image:results.scannedImage)
                                                    ^
                                                                 ?? <#default value#>
    /Users/administrator/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/edge_detection-1.0.4/ios/Classes/HomeViewController.swift:29:49:
    note: force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'
            var imagePath = saveImage(image:results.scannedImage)
```

Flutter doctor showed the following:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.3-pre.37, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G3020, locale de-AT)
    • Flutter version 1.15.3-pre.37 at /Users/sebastiankubeck/Software/flutter
    • Framework revision 6dc3bfaa98 (2 days ago), 2020-02-07 18:28:02 -0800
    • Engine revision 6158f03ef5
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.8.0 514a8d4c84)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sebastiankubeck/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • macOS      • macOS      • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G3020
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.87
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

The project was created with an older version of flutter and it seems that the ios directory is not updated correctly. Alternatively, it could be that my CocoaPods version is too new, so I tried 1.7.5, which wasn't successful either.

Comment: Which version of swift is used on your project? If you are in Swift 5 try to downgrade to Swift 4. I recommend to create an issue on their GitHub if you still have the problem: https://github.com/sawankumarbundelkhandi/edge_detection/issues

Comment: Swift 5. Downgrading didn't work. There is already a pull request and I'll try to fix it manually. Thank you! https://github.com/sawankumarbundelkhandi/edge_detection/pull/17

Comment: Can you please try setting the global-platform in Pod file to 9 or 10? It's the first line on the Pod file that is usually commented.